# Ruby Active Storage blob keys?

Tags: ruby, rails

What are the security impacts of revealing the keys to the user? I googled around and only found the ruby documentation. But did not find any article on how it affects security. Is it just because of 24 character of base58 or someone could enlighten me?

> key: 
>   Returns the key pointing to the file on the service that's
>   associated with this blob. The key is the secure-token format from
>   Rails in lower case. So it'll look like: xtapjjcjiudrlk3tmwyjgpuobabd.
>   This key is not intended to be revealed directly to the user. Always
>   refer to blobs using the #signed_id or a verified form of the key.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-key